# Using GitLab CI with C#

Tags: c#, gitlab-ci

I've been working on a C# application, and wanted to try out the GitLab CI. All I can see is Ruby and can't find any information on how to build a C# application using it.

When I run the test settings, it just hangs on pending as I'm not sure what the YAML file should have in it.

Is this possible or am I being stupid?

Thanks,
PXgamer

Comment: My answer from another question should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33904017/5398655

Comment: @Grisha Don't worry, I ended up using Visual Studio Online ;)

Thank you though,
- PXgamer