# gitlab CI runner C# dependencies all fail in MSbuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a runner (configured with a slight modification of [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38211190/7173397)) which should build and unit test a solution which contains an ASP.NET CORE project, a JS less web front end, and a unit test project.

However, when MSbuild attempts to build the project every single dependency fails (over 150 error messages) with error NU1001 in every project.

This is in addition to some very weird behavior- it tried to use visual studio 2012 to build even though VS 2012 has never been installed on this machine. It also refuses to accept the %project_name argument from the original script. I had to hard-code a location and version to even get it to the build stage.

The nuget from the original script was removed since it was breaking.Later i found documentation stating that nuget now automatically refreshes packages on build, so it doesn't need to be re-added.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is a gitlab-ci issue. Focus your debugging efforts on executing that MSBuild command on the server (or within the container) associated with the runner you're using.

I recommend using `before_script` to call out to a script that *verifies the dependencies needed by your pipeline*. For example, your pre-build script could verify that MSBuild, NuGet, and Git are on the path of your runner/VM/Container (this lets you control these prerequisites using Puppet or Powershell DSC rather than managing them within the pipeline).

`nuget restore` should be called as part of a `restore` stage rather than in `before_script`. The restored packages can be passed between stages as artifacts.

You are double-quoting your invocation of MSBuild in your `build` job. Here's how I'm invoking MSBuild in a pipeline I'm currently working with:

`build_dev:
  stage: build
  script:
    - MSBuild $env:TARGETS /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./*/bin
    <<: *default_expiration
  <<: *default_tags`

In this scenario, my `before_script` has verified that `MSBuild` is on the path, so I'm free to use it. It might refer to MSBuild 12.0 or 14.0 depending on the runner. `$env:TARGETS` is from a gitlab-ci variable; it points to an MSBuild file, `build.targets`.

I believe you're using a basic `shell` executor; some things get easier when you specify `shell = powershell` in your runner config, Powershell syntax is flat out better for piecing together pipelines.

Finally, whether or not MSBuild automatically restores NuGet dependencies is really up to the way your `.csproj` files are written. I would argue that it's best to have `nuget restore` as a separate step. Having a separate step comes in handy when, for example, you need to restore Nuget packages that are used by MSBuild itself.

Verify that simply running MSBuild against your solution file automatically restores NuGet packages by running MSBuild yourself in the command line. I don't think gitlab-ci will affect the success of that command.

Comment: I'm on a new laptop since posting this question, so i had to do most CI/runner steps again.

I have no idea how any of these scripts work, and i tried running MSbuild in cmd and it doesn't run in the folder of the solution, nor in the MSbuild folder. I've verified that MSbuild is indeed present at the location of the script up top.

I've spent several days messing with the yml and your suggestions and got loads of yml errors on CI.

I don't even know where to start/fix anymore.