# Nuget restore myapp.sln is not being recognized as a command in Gitlab CI/CD for ASP.NET Web forms app

Tags: webforms, continuous-integration, nuget, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm trying to setup CI/CD for my ASP.NET Web forms application. I need to do it in Gitlab. So I researched a lot and used the templates for dotnet CI on Gitlab.
These are some of the sources I used the script from.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38211190

https://medium.com/@gabriel.faraday.barros/gitlab-ci-cd-with-net-framework-39220808b18f

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/dotNET.gitlab-ci.yml

Following is the script I have in my gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
    NUGET_PATH: 'C:\Nuget\nuget.exe'
    MSBUILD_PATH: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
    
stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# before_script:
#   - $NUGET_PATH restore ..MyApp\MyApp.sln

build-job:
  stage: build
  tags:
    - myapp-dev
  script:
    - cd c:\dharani\git\MyApp
    - '& "$NUGET_PATH" restore ..\MyApp\MyApp.sln'
    - '& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /p:Configuration=Debug /clp:ErrorsOnly ..\MyApp\MyApp.sln'
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 days
    paths:
      - '.\bin\Release\Publish\'
```

However I'm not able to run the nuget restore command. It gives the following error-

```
$ & "C:\Nuget\nuget.exe" restore "..\MyApp\MyApp.sln"
& : The term 'C:\Nuget\nuget.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Windows\TEMP\build_script2722061214\script.ps1:235 char:3
```

I have downloaded the latest nuget executable to my local and am using the local nuget and MSbuild paths following according to the sources. I'm new to CI/CD and I'm not even sure how to debug the issue. I directly used the path in the command instead of variable, removed/added quotes and all other syntaxes, still couldn't get it to work. Without the restore command and running just the MS build on sln file, I'm getting

```
C:\dharani\git\MyApp\MyApp\Services\Service.cs(13,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'AuthorizeNet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

SO I assumed restoring nuget packages should solve the issue. I've ran it multiple times with different syntaxes and also added nuget path to environment variables(not sure that's even a solution to this)

Basically I'm just trying to setup CI/CD for my ASP.NET 4.5 Web Forms application, build the app, publish the files onto a folder and copy those files to IIS server folder. I'm stuck at build stage only. If someone could please guide me where I'm going wrong, would highly appreciate it. Also any good sources to help me with the whole CI/CD for ASP.NET Web forms app please.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your problem, just 2 general suggestions: 1. Try to replicate the commands directly on your runner. 2. I don't think you need the surrounding ''. You should be able to write - C:\Nuget\nuget.exe restore ..\MyApp\MyApp.sln

Comment: Also edit your gitlab-ci.yml directly in the Gitlab Pipeline editor, that way it will be linted live

Comment: @andymeissner I am using the pipeline editor, I don't even know another method. Do I need a Dotnet image in the script? I'm currently using a shared runner(Windows) in my company repository. Can you please tell me high level steps how I can run these commands on runner directly. Thank you!

Comment: The runner should be a computer or VM that someone connected to your Gitlab instance. You should try to find out if there exists a C:\Nuget\nuget.exe on this runner. Access to this runner would be something like remote desktop connection

Comment: why not use `dotnet restore` or `msbuild -t:restore`?  nuget.exe is a legacy way to restore packages that has additional complexity and failure modes, so using msbuild directly will just increase your pipeline reliability.

Comment: @zivkan But I thought ```dotnet restore``` or ```dotnet run``` work only for .net core projects. However I did try dotnet restore command and it said no packages to restore. Later when I run ```MsBuild MyApp.sln``` command I get ```Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly```. I checked the packages and reference for that error package, the dll file exists, so this tells me that the dotnet restore did not work. Please correct me if I'm wrong.